# Unable to upload to Azure BLOB storage via Az Module or Az/CLI

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-blob-storage

I've used to have a quite ordinary code to upload files to **Azure BLOB storage**. I post just the most important lines:

```bsh
$context = New-AzStorageContext $StorageName -StorageAccountKey $Key -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
Set-AzStorageBlobContent -Context $context -Container 'spfx' `
  -File $path -Blob "$Package/v$PackageVersion/$([Path]::GetFileName($path))" `
  -ServerTimeoutPerRequest 1800 -ClientTimeoutPerRequest 1800 -ConcurrentTaskCount 1 -Force
```

It locks for a long time than I get this exception:
[image]

The **app registration** used to login has **full access** to the **resource group** which hosts the storage account. The container is configured to allow just anonymous read. As you can see for write access I use a secret.

I tried to use **Az/CLI** instead fo **Az Module** but I get an error message the same:
[image]

Using the **portal** UI I'm able to add files to the BLOB storage.

If there's literally anything I can try, please let me know. Tell me also if you need more info to help me.

As always any help will be really appreciated!

Giacomo S. S.

Comment: I want to add creating another script with do just very essential uploading operations. I'm still not able to understand why in the more complex one this doesn't work. I tried to remove code, deps, but _mistery_ still persists...

Answer (score 1):

In the second error, you've got a backslash in the path: temp%5Cout.json
Check the script to see where it's coming from

Comment: This appear only the error message, input value of Az/CLI are correct. Very weird...

Comment: if the character between temp and out is a '\' it would cause this error

Comment: at the end I discovered that storage name was invalid